# Where to keep in-memory data shared between users

Tags: java, spring

In my spring boot app, I want to keep the number of users who subscribe to each websocket channel.

I'd like to do this using a concurrent hashmap, but I don't know where I should keep this data structure, so all users share it. From my understanding, putting it in a component doesn't lead to being "shared" between requests.

I have to mention that I never touched sessions in my app, as authentication is based on JWT.

Comment: Does it also not work if you put it in the component as `static` variable?

Comment: Yeah, but I avoid using static member variables as much as possible.

Comment: What about a bean with singleton scope?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Spring has a good caching mechanism. If you are using Spring Boot see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html

Comment: I don't want to cache data, I want to keep a counter on some items which are updated frequently. It's should even be thread-safe. I don't think caching is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Service/Bean which holds data in ehCache, good example [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-caching-and-ehcache-example/)

I would not use a Map.

Based on [Arian Hosseinzadeh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1664315/arian-hosseinzadeh) below which I think is correct. Just create a normal @Service Bean, it will be a singleton by default.

Comment: Is it a good idea to put data that is intended to be thread safe and critical in a cache? isn't cache supposed to keep transient data, which is cleared every once in a while without control over it?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh yes I think you're right, answer modified.